# HTML email template not working while sending mail through apex

Tags: apex, email-template

I am trying to send an html email template body in the mail from apex code by using messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate method but it is sending plain text not html body.

Here is the code :

```
 EmailTemplate tempID = [SELECT Id,HTMLValue,Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName =: label.ApprovalProcessEmailTemplate];
            string emailBody= messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(tempID.Id,newQuotes.OwnerId,newQuotes.Id).getHtmlBody();
            mail.setHtmlBody(emailBody);
            List<String> users = new List<String>{ userInfo.getUserEmail()};
            mail.setToAddresses(users);
            
            
            Messaging.SendEmailResult [] result = Messaging.sendEmail(new list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {mail});
```

Expected :

[image]

Actual :

[image]

**email is not sending in proper html format.**

Comment: How does your template code look like? Are you using any table?

Comment: yes it uses html table to structure the details